# line chart and bar chart don't align against the same index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, linechart

I'm trying to plot a pandas dataframe as a bar plot and a line plot.

This MWE sums up what I'm looking at:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,2), columns = ['A', 'B'])

test_df['A'] = test_df['A'].cumsum()
test_df['B'] = test_df['B'].cumsum()
test_df.index += 1
```

I then plot the bars:

```
ax = test_df.plot(kind='bar', colors=['red', 'blue'], figsize = (13.5,6))
```

This plots fine as expected against the index of the df:
[image]

I then further manipulate the data in some manner to form an upper bound to be plotted as a line against the bars:

```
test_df['C'] = test_df.index
test_df['Upper'] = 4 * (test_df['C']/5)**0.5
test_df['Upper'].plot()
```

This however doesn't work as intended:
[image]

- The x axis has shifted and now not all of the data is visible
- Even if the `xlim` is changed the line plot doesn't begin over index 1 as I would expect from the pandas df index.

How can I solve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things happening here in your example.

1) When you make a bar chart of `'A'` and `'B'` using the `plot(kind='bar')` method of `test_df`, pandas creates a plot where the values in `test_df.index` are used as the x-axis tick labels for the corresponding pairs in columns `'A'` and `'B'`. I'm assuming pandas does this because bar charts are usually used with categorical variables on the x-axis. This can be illustrated by the following code:

```
>>> test_df.index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                     11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
>>> ax = test_df[['A', 'B']].plot(kind='bar', color=['red', 'blue'])
```

Which produces:

[image: Bar Chart]

What this means is that the x-axis tick labels in your first plot are not the actual x-values at which the values are plotted. Instead `1` is actually at x = 0 becuase it is the first value of the index and `20` is at x = 19. You can deduce this by checking the x-axis limits:

```
>>> ax.get_xlim()
(-0.5, 19.5)
```

2) Calling `test_df['Upper'].plot()` (without `kind='bar'`) plots the values in the `'Upper'` column and uses `test_df.index` as the x-coordinates. This call uses the current axes and looks like it also changes the x-axis limits to fit the most recent plotted data, whose x-values are 1 through 20. If you check the axis limits on the second plot they will be `(1.0, 20.0)`.

To get around all this, I would recommend *not* incrementing the index and keeping it from 0-19 before plotting your data. That way you know all of the x-coordinates are the same. Then after plotting them you can set explicitly set the x-tick labels with `ax.set_xticklabels(['your', 'x', 'tick', 'labels'])`.

There is probably a `kwarg` you can add to `df.plot(kind='bar', ...)` that will set the x-coordinates to plot bars at, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, it all seems quite unpythonic but it works, for what's it's worth to future readers, for all bars to show I had to change the `plt.xlim(-1,20)`, then I couldn't change the tick labels using the command in your answer, instead I had to use `plt.xticks(range(0,20), range(1,21))` which works.

Comment: No problem! It probably seems unpythonic because the `df.plot()` is a convenience method (basically a wrapper for matplotlib) that makes assumptions about what you're trying to plot. If you want to avoid these assumptions I'd suggest getting familiar with matplotlib's object-oriented plotting interface as it's more explicit and gives finer control over plot elements IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can align line chart to bar chart with the following code:

```
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[0]-0.5, ax.get_xlim()[1]+0.5)
```